# Sufficient statistics are not unique?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, likelihood, sufficient-statistics

I am currently studying *sufficiency statistics*. My notes say the following:

> A statistic $T(\mathbf{Y})$ is sufficient for $\theta$ if, and only if, for all $\theta \in \Theta$,
>
> $$L(\theta; \mathbf{y}) = g(T(\mathbf{y}), \theta) \times h(\mathbf{y}),$$
>
> where the function $g(\cdot)$ depends on $\theta$ and the statistic $T(\mathbf{Y})$, while the function $h(\cdot)$ does not contain $\theta$.
>
> *Sufficient statistics are not unique:*
>
> Any one-to-one transformation of a sufficient statistic is again a sufficient statistic.

Is this not a contradiction? That is, if sufficient statistics are not unique, then should it not be the case that any one-to-one transformation of a sufficient statistic is *not necessarily* a sufficient statistic? One would expect that any one-to-one transformation of a sufficient statistic is again a sufficient statistic if and only if sufficient statistics *are* unique, no?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone would please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, if they were unique, a transformation of the sufficient statistic wouldn't be a sufficient statistic (unless it is identity transformation). For example, let $T(\mathbf{y})=\bar y$, i.e. the sample mean. A 1-1 transformation here would be scaling, i.e. $T_1(\mathbf{y})=2\bar y$. This means any information that can be provided with the sample mean can also be provided with $2$ times the sample mean.